# checking for two underscores next to each other

Tags: c++

my code is supposed to check if two underscores are next to each other, on the beginning or on the end of a string and more other rules..... problem is when the code finds 2 underscores in whole string, it prints Chyba but it should not. it is supposed to print Chyba only if it finds something like this `abc__abc` but it works like this `abc_abc_abc` >> chyba ... any solutions?

```
 void Convert(string input){
    string output = "";
    string flag = "";
    bool underscore = false;
    bool uppercase = false;
    if ( islower(input[0]) == false){
        cout << "Chyba!" <<endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < input.size(); i++){
        if ( (isalpha( input[i] ) || (input[i]) == '_') == false){
            cout << "Chyba!" <<endl;
            return;
        }
        if (islower(input[i])){
            if (underscore){
                underscore = false;
                output += toupper(input[i]);
            }
            else
                output += input[i];

        }
        else if (isupper(input[i])){
            if (flag == "C" || uppercase){
                cout << "Chyba!"<<endl;
                return;
            }
            flag = "Java";
            output += '_';
            output += tolower(input[i]);

        }
        else if (input[i] == '_'){
            if (flag == "Java" || underscore){
            cout << "Chyba!" <<endl;
            return;
            }
            flag = "C";
            underscore = true;
        }

    }


    for (int i=input.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
      if (input[i] == '_'){
            if (flag == "Java" || underscore){
            cout << "Chybaaa!" <<endl;
            return;
            }
            flag = "C";
            underscore = true;
        }
    }
cout << output <<endl;
}
```

Comment: You set the `underscore` flag to `true`, but never set it back to `false`.  If you set it to `false` when the character after an underscore is **not** itself an underscore, you'll get what you want.

Comment: Please elaborate what you like to find and what not and the result of each

Answer (score 9):

```
bool containsAdjacentUnderscores = std::search_n(begin(input), end(input), 2, '_') != end(input);
```

Comment: +1, but you should mention what the returne value is and how to use it.